# Jframe. Get value from ComboBox, in another class, using getSelectedItem()

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have main jframe code in class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CreateBuildAndPr extends JFrame  {

....some code...

    private JComboBox comboBoxClients = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox comboBoxBranch = new JComboBox();

    ....some code...

        public String getClient(){
            String getClient = comboBoxClients.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //System.out.printf("\nClient: \n" + getClient);
            return getClient;
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public CreateBuildAndPr() {
            lblCreateBuildAnd.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
            comboBoxBranch.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1a", "2a", "3a", "4a"}));
            comboBoxClients.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3"}));
            textFieldInfo.setColumns(10);
            btnCreateBuild.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    CreateNewBuildAndPr callSe = new CreateNewBuildAndPr();
                    callSe.newBuild();
                }
            });

            initGUI();
        }
```

So when I call this method getClient(), in CreateBuildAndPr class, the selected value from ComboBox is correct. Lets say: "2".
But when I call from other class, always the return result is "1".
Here is the other class:

```
public class CreateNewBuildAndPr extends ConnectionsUrlAndDb {

    @Test
    public void newBuild() {


    CreateBuildAndPr createBuildAndPr = new CreateBuildAndPr();



        System.out.printf("\n\nSelenium: " +createBuildAndPr.getClient());
        String info = createBuildAndPr.getInfo();
        System.out.printf("\n\nSelenium: " +info);
        String branch = createBuildAndPr.getBranch();
        System.out.printf("\n\nSelenium: " +branch);

... more code .... }
```

How I can correct getSelectedItem in other class?

Comment: How is the first frame being closed? I do not see a wait till the first frame closed in the `newBuild` method.

Comment: There is no wait. jFrame is only CreateBuildAndPr. CreateNewBuildAndPr is only class, not jFrame. So the main frame is never closed, just call other methods from other class.

Comment: So when is the value of the combo changed? When are you supposed to print it? The Frame will be displayed and your code following the `new` call will continue. It doesn't wait for you to select the combo. You may want to use a modal dialog and wait for it to close before you print the selected value.

Comment: When the frame is opened, I choose from ComboBox, then i Press the button. After the pressing the button, all the values are set to 1.

Comment: *"..in another class.."*  This part is 'OOP 101'.  If you don't know how to do that, you should refrain from making GUIs and figure it out in command line apps.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, I know how to do it. I do same for jTextField, and works perfect.

Comment: So if you know how to do that part, it hardly seems relevant to waste words in the title mentioning it.  BTW - For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
CreateBuildAndPr createBuildAndPr = new CreateBuildAndPr();
```

creates a new object of that class. What you want is to reference the existing one with the `JComboBox` and its selected value. The solution would be to pass the combobox (or even a reference to the frame that contains it) to the `CreateNewBuildAndPr` object as a parameter.

For example modify your `CreateNewBuildAndPr` class to contain a variable

```
private JComboBox clientCombo;
```

and define a new constructor in that class as

```
public CreateNewBuildAndPr (JComboBox clientCombo)
{
    this.clientCombo = clientCombo
}
```

and in your `JFrame` `ActionListener` pass the combobox as a variable

```
CreateNewBuildAndPr callSe = new CreateNewBuildAndPr(comboBoxClients);
```

which will allow you to reference this combobox in `CreateNewBuildAndPr` class.

```
clientCombo.getSelectedItem()...
```

I just used the single `JComboBox` as an example here. If you passed the entire GUI object you could access it and use its methods, such as `getInfo()` that you seem to have there.